# Extract and take average of csv column based on condition

Tags: python

I'm taking a class on Python, so I'm definitely not using it on a day to day basis but am trying my best to learn. One of my assignments is to read data from a csv file and get the average beginning weight of males and females in the file. I'm not allowed to use Pandas or any other external packages so am just importing csv to read the data. My issue is, I can do the calculations for the first condition but when it gets to the second condition, it's returning the error, 'division by zero.' I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and was hoping someone could help me. I have confirmed the values for males and females by looking at the file and there is data for both.

This is the code that's returning 'division by zero.' If I reverse the rows and do males first instead of females, it does the same for females. If I just print out f_weight and m_weight, f_weight is populated, m_weight returns [].

```
import csv

def avg_start_weight(csv_data):
    
    with open(csv_data, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        f_weight = [float(row[1]) for row in csv_reader if row[0] == 'F']
        m_weight = [float(cell[1]) for cell in csv_reader if cell[0] == 'M']
        f_average = sum(f_weight) / len(f_weight)
        m_average = sum(m_weight) / len(m_weight)
        print(f'2. The average female beginning weight is {f_average:.2f} and the average male beginning weight is {m_average:.2f}')
        csv_file.close()

csv_data = 'freshman_kgs.csv'        
avg_start_weight(csv_data)
```

I did get it to work this way but am guessing I shouldnt need to close and re-open the file each time I want to test a different condition, so wanted to see if I could get some help figuring out what Im doing wrong:

```
import csv
def avg_start_weight(csv_data):
    
    with open(csv_data, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        f_weight = [float(row[1]) for row in csv_reader if row[0] == 'F']
        f_average = sum(f_weight) / len(f_weight)
        print(f'2. Average female beginning weight: {f_average:.2f}')
        csv_file.close()
    
    with open(csv_data, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        m_weight = [float(row[1]) for row in csv_reader if row[0] == 'M']
        m_average = sum(m_weight) / len(m_weight)
        print(f'Average male beginning weight: {m_average:.2f}')
        csv_file.close()

csv_data = "freshman_kgs.csv"
avg_start_weight(csv_data)
```

The last thing I tried was this and it also returns 'division by zero' depending on which calculation I put second:

```
import csv

def avg_start_weight(csv_data):
    with open(csv_data, newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')      


        m_weight = [float(row[1]) for row in csv_reader if row[0] == 'M']
        m_weight_avg = sum(m_weight) / len(m_weight)
        print(f'The average beginning weight for males was {m_weight_avg:.2f}')
            
        f_weight = [float(row[1]) for row in csv_reader if row[0] == 'F']
        f_weight_avg = sum(f_weight) / len(f_weight)
        print(f'The average beginning weight for females was {f_weight_avg:.2f}')

csv_data = "freshman_kgs.csv"
avg_start_weight(csv_data)
```

I'm not at all asking for someone to do my homework for me, I'm trying my best to understand this and figure it out myself but am stuck. I really appreciate any help that I get. Ive been looking at others questions and most of them are using Pandas so weren't of much use to me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of thing wrong with your code.
the line `csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')` produces an iterable which you need to process to get at specific lines of data, also when you utilize the with open construct, it isn't necessary to close the file, since that is automatically handled for you.  Here is how I would write the required code as a reference:

```
def avg_start_weight(csv_data, newline=''):
    weights = {'M':[], 'F':[]}
    with open(csv_data, mode='r') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
        for lines in csv_file:
            if lines[0] == 'M'  or lines[0] == 'F':
                weights[lines[0]].append(int(lines[1]))
    print(f"Average Female Weight = {sum(weights['F'])/len(weights['F']):.2f}")
    print(f"Average Male Weight = {sum(weights['M'])/len(weights['F']):.2f}")
```

Notice:  I used a dictionary structure to hold a list of Male and female weights.  While reading the lines of the csv file, I add new values to the appropriate dictionary key as defined by the first item in each line.  Also note that I converted the input data from a string to an integer as I was adding each item to it's appropriate list.